# Android how can i hook native exported functions from a shared library *.so?

Tags: android

It needs to work even on older versions of android (3.x and above) specifically the old Sony "PS Certified" devices, the device im working with (Sony Tablet S) i have seen reports online that installing the xposed framework will brick the device however you CAN get root

So is there any other way to hook native functions on android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Frida framework for that purpose - [link](https://www.frida.re). In short, it will enable you to hook native/Dalvik routines on rooted/non-rooted devices and write hook logic in JS. The framework also has python bindings which can provide means for automation. Following is a short explanation about the usage flow for analysis of APK file:

- Rooted device:

  - there is a great quick start guide on the Frida's site - [link](https://www.frida.re/docs/android/)
  - [here](https://www.notsosecure.com/instrumenting-native-android-functions-using-frida/) is an example of hooking native function for a running APK file, but you can also use the framework to analyze arbitrary native executable which you can attach to or spawn a new process.
- Not-rooted device:

  - in that case you will need to re-package APK and include server library to it. [Here](https://koz.io/using-frida-on-android-without-root/) is a good example how to do it.

The framework is in active development and cross-platform/arch supported. If more granular control is needed, you can even develop lower-level apps (e.g. in C) against it's API library.